# vim - call function inside 'replace' expression

Tags: vim

I understand you can call a function in a vim search/replace operation.  For example:

```
%s/regex/\=localtime()/g
```

will replace anything matching 'regex' with the current epoch time.  The problem is, I can't add anything else to the 'replace' expression.  For example:

```
%s/regex/epoch: \=localtime()/g
```

does not treat 'localtime' as a function anymore.  Rather it just prints 'epoch: =localtime()' as a string in the replacement text. The intention is for it to print 'epoch: 1353085984' instead.

Is there any way to call a function from within an arbitrary section of a replacement expression?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once you use a replace-expression, it must be the entire replacement. You can use String concatenation in your expression (and refer to captured elements via `submatch(1)` instead of `\1`), like this:

```
:%s/regex/\='epoch: ' . localtime()/g
```

Comment: Perfect answer!  Concise, simple, and accurate.  Thanks!

Comment: Example with parameters `substitute(submatch(1), "_", "%20", "g")`