# vim regular expression substitution quantifier

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

how do i quantify the replacement portion of a vim search/replace expression?

```
:%s/x\{4\}/yyyy/g
```

will replace every occurrence of 4 x's with 4 y's.

```
:%s/x\{4\}/y\{4\}/g
```

replaces the 4 x's with "y{4}"

how do i modify that so that i do not have to insert 4 separate y's but instead "quantify" a single y.

Answer (score 4):

The solution seems more troublesome than its worth:

```
:%s/w\{4}/\=repeat('y',4)/g
```

Comment: that is precisely what i was looking for. my example, replacing 4 x's with 4 y's was simplified. my concrete problem was using 100 of the same character in my replacement clause. thanks to all who responded. this is the solution. i trust someone will mark it as such.

Comment: previous solution answers my question. however, what is correct format to get the replacement clause to repeat 4 y's followed by the characters in the find clause (back reference), i.e. how replace 4 x's with 4 y's and four x's? i tried :%s/\(x\{4\}\)/\=repeat('y',4)\1/g ... doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `%s/\(x\{4\}\)/\=repeat('y',4).submatch(1)/g`

Answer (score 0):

OP wrote:

> what is correct format to get the replacement clause to repeat 4 y's
>   followed by the characters in the find clause (back reference), i.e.
>   how replace 4 x's with 4 y's

**Answer**

*Replaces all occurances of `xxxx` with four `y`'s followed by a backreference*

```
%s/\(x\{4\}\)/\=repeat('y',4).submatch(1)/g
```

**before**

```
hello xxxx there xxxx end
```

**after**

```
hello yyyyxxxx there yyyyxxxx end
```

Thanks to *@romainl* for the original answer, and *@Ingo Karkat* for [answering a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421430/vim-call-function-inside-replace-expression)